# Php downlaod warning: "is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous"

Tags: php, zip

I need create zip file and download it, after delete, but after downloading Google Chrome give warning "is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous" if i go to direct link and download file its working fine but download in php give warning. How i can fix it ?

```
$zip_file = public_path().'/storage/file.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ( $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    exit("message");
    }
$zip->addFromString(basename('file.cs'),$plugin);
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();

header("Cache-Control: public");
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($zip_file)."\"");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile($zip_file);
unlink($zip_file);
exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure `zip` is a valid MIME type, you can add the following to your htaccess file if you are using Apache:

```
AddType application/zip .zip
```

If that does not work for you, this support document from Google says there is a way to ask for a review in the search console; others have reported using it with success:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249